# AJAX ModalPopupExtender not working when published to web server

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I developed a small web app that uses the AJAX Control Toolkit.  On my computer, all of the AJAX controls work properly.  However, when I publish my site to my web server, the ModalPopupExtender no longer works.

- My environment: Windows 10, Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
- Server environment: Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5.9600
- Using AJAX Control Toolkit ver 16.1

When I click the button that should bring up the modal popup window, nothing happens.  No error is displayed, even when the site is viewed on the web server using the actual URL (http://servername/appname).  What is really strange is that if I go to the site in IIS and click the "Browse *.80 (http)" link, it works properly (using the URL http://localhost/appname)

I know the ACT is working, because I have another button with an ConfirmButtonExtender on it and that works fine (both on my machine and the server).  As the ModalPopupExtender uses a CSS file, I was suspicious that it wasn't set up properly.  My site uses master pages, so I added the reference to the CSS file in the Master page.  I know it is working on my computer, because if I make a small change to the CSS file it is reflected on the popup panel.

In IIS, the site is configured to use an Application Pool.  I have set the application pool to use a domain service account.  This account has full read/write permissions on the folder containing the web site files & folders.

I feel like I am missing something simple, but the nature of this is making it hard to research (too many false links when "server" is included in the search).  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions anyone could give me.  If code examples are needed, just let me know which code is required.

Comment: Is this issue related to yours? https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/346

Comment: MikhailTymchukDX - Unfortunately my issue seems slightly different, as I do not see the error message mentioned there.  Thank you for your reply though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging with a ACT tech on the GitHub site, we eventually found a fix for this.  He had me install the latest version of the toolkit (v17.1.1) using NuGet.  Once I did that, the ModalPopupExtender worked correctly on my web server.

Instructions for how to do this are found here:

https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Step-by-Step-Installation-Guide#nuget-package